# Canvas `strokeStyle` opacity looks darker in Chrome than in Firefox/Edge

Tags: javascript, canvas, opacity, alpha, particles

This is an odd one.

Setting `strokeStyle` on a canvas with an RGBA value results in the drawn lines looking slightly more opaque on Chrome than in Firefox and Edge.

On Chrome, the opacity of the lines appears to be about 0.1 higher than the opacity used by Firefox and Edge.

I am not using global alpha or any destination options; this is a plain canvas where I'm drawing lines with a fixed alpha. I haven't been able to find any documentation pertaining to this; part of me wants to dismiss it as an illusion, but the difference is real and apparent across all devices.

**Chrome**

[image]

**Firefox (Edge looks identical)**

[image]

*Both browsers running identical code with identical animation settings; `strokeStyle` alpha of `0.2`; canvas filled with solid white on each draw call.*

**What is causing Chrome to render strokes with a slightly higher apparent opacity than Firefox/Edge?**

I think this won't necessarily be fixable, but it is slightly frustrating and I'd like to know the reasons why I'm seeing this effect.

It's not a hugely major issue, but as I think the screenshots show, it is perceptible, and I'm at a loss as to why it's occurring.

Comment: Does the canvas have any `background-color`? What's the clear color?

Comment: @IvanRubinson clear colour `rgba(255,255,255,1)`, no `background-color`. I have just now replaced the `fillRect(...)` with `clearRect(0,0,width,height)` (removed fill altogether since it's not actually needed) but no change in the effect by doing this.